# Finding velocity in optimization problem

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, optimization, physics

> Given $s=-16t^2+192t+144$, what is the velocity when $s=0$?

This is part of a larger optimization problem which I solved, except for this last part. The critical point occurs at $t=6$, so after $t=6$ the position function is decreasing since the slope ($s^{\prime}$) is negative.

To find the velocity when $s=0$, I tried $s=-16t^2+192t+144=0$, and quadratic formula gives the roots, which are $t=-12.71$ and $t=0.71$. Shouldn't we use the positive root, $t=0.71$, since $t$ must be positive, because $t$ is time and can't be negative?

The text answer says $-214.72$ but that comes from using the negative root, and I don't understand why negative time $t$ is used. Is $-214.72$ incorrect?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't you just evaluate the derivative at the time for which $s(t)=0$, which occurs twice since there are two real solutions for it. A plot of $s$ is [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-16+*+t^2+%2B+192+*+t+%2B+144+%3D0). You can see it hits $0$ twice. Evaluating $s'(t)$ at these times gives me a speed of 214.66 for one crossing and -214.66 for the other.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply $-1$ on both sides of the equation and substitute $s=0$ to get $16t^2-192t-144=0$. Then, solve with result from quadratic variables. Let $a=16$, $b=-192$, $c=-144$ and solve with
$$
x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
$$

Comment: Ok, but there will be two roots, which one will I use? thanks

Comment: $t$ must be positive.

Comment: @kmitov There is nothing in the problem statement that says $t$ must be positive.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 $t$ represents time, I forgot to mention it. So it must be positive

Comment: @bryansis2010 $-214.72$ comes from using the negative $t$ root value, $-12.71$, why is the negative root used here if $t$ must be positive since it is time? thanks. +1

Comment: Please, look at the calculations more carefuly.

Answer (score 1):

D=11520

$107,3312629=\sqrt{11520}$

$12,70820393=(-96-107,3312629)/(-16)$

$-214,6625258 = -32*12,70820393+192$

Comment: the two roots are $t=-12.71$ and $t=0.71$, why is the negative root used to give an answer of $-214.72$? is that a mistake? Shouldn't we use $t=0.71$ instead of $t=-12.71$?

Comment: Dear sir, I used the positive root. When one the numerator and denominator have the same signs, the quotient  im positive.

Answer (score -1):

well Dear kmitov
if we solve the quadratic equation we get to 2 roots
12.708 or -0.708

but this answer is not the answer quoted by user 437158
can you help me on this

further velocity and s has a realtion

ds/dt (differentail)

if we find velocity by differentiating

it is idependent of variable  s=0

and ds/dt = -32t+192

if we put velocity v = o  then we get the time when body was supposed to be staionery

at t= 192/32=0.1875 second , the body was sationery but where it was from its origin s=o

it means that we should find instantous velocity when t= 0.1875

so we may say that instanous velocity was vt= 192-6 units when s=0

thanks
Stormer wiki ghubaroo@gmail.com

Comment: $s(t)=a t^2+ v_0 t+ s_0$